# Filter Generic Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, generic-foreign-key

Is there a more "Python/Django" way to query/filter objects by generic foreign key? I'm trying to get all FullCitation objects for a particular software, where is_primary is True.

I know I can't do this but I want to do something like this:

```
ct_supported = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="supportedprogram", model="software")
primary_citations = FullCitation.objects.filter(content_type__name=ct_supported, object_id__in='', is_primary=True)
```

models.py

```
class FullCitation(models.Model)
    # the software to which this citation belongs
    # either a supported software program or a non-supported software program

    limit = models.Q(app_label = 'myprograms', model = 'supportedprogram') | models.Q(app_label = 'myprograms', model = 'nonsupportedprogram') 
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType), limit_choices_to = limit, )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    is_primary = models.BooleanField(help_text="Is this the Primary Citation for the software program?")

class NonSupportedProgram(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank = True)
    full_citation = generic.GenericRelation('FullCitation')

class SupportedProgram(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank = True)
    full_citation = generic.GenericRelation('FullCitation')
    # and a bunch of other fields.....
```

views.py    # My current attempt

```
primary_citations = []
sw_citations = sw.full_citations.all()
    for x in sw_citations:
        if x.is_primary:
            primary_citations.append(x)
```

Comment: Quickfix: use a list comprehesion [cit for cit in sw.full_citations.all() if cit.is_primary]

Comment: Thank you, @Alvaro! That definitely helps. Just wondering if there is a way to filter on the FullCitation object itself that would be more Django-ish...if not, I'll definitely use the list comprehension!

Comment: You can also use a generator comprehension, `(x for x in y)` to delay the database query and only perform it when neccessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comprehensions should be a last resort for filtering QuerySets. Far better to let them remain as QuerySets as long as you can. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
ct_supported = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(SupportedProgram))
primary_citations = FullCitation.objects.filter(content_type=ct_supported, is_primary=True)
```

**Updated:**
If you want to filter for a specific SupportedProgram instance, do this:

```
my_supported = SupportedProgram.objects.get(id=instance_id_goes_here)
ct_supported = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(SupportedProgram))
primary_citations = FullCitation.objects.filter(content_object=my_supported, content_type=ct_supported, is_primary=True)
```

Comment: that's almost there but not quite (definitely in the vein of what I'm looking for!)- I need one more 'level' of filtering. I want to filter not just on the SupportedProgram models but on a specific instance of Supported Program. So, I want all FullCitations where the SupportedProgram is, specifically, 'Program1' and then, of those FullCitations, I want only those where is_primary=True....

Comment: @steph Updated to filter for a specific SupportedProgram instance.